# how do i know if java jdk is installled

Tags: java, ubuntu

I downloaded java from oracle site but am not sure if JDK is installed with it,ran `java-version` to check and got that result

```
java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Simply type java -version, it will give you the details , if you do not get, it means java is not yet installed.

Comment: You could search the directory hierarchy for the `java` executable.

Comment: Since you ran `java --version` and you got an output, that means you have java installed so you can create java applications

Answer (score 2):

You have Java installed with the JDK kit. You wouldn't be getting that output otherwise.

If you are on an older version, just type `java`. That works too

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 11 there is no separate JRE for Oracle and OpenJDK java distributions.

There is only JDK. And JDK has everything that JRE has. So in your case you have Java 12 JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `jshell` in the terminal.

Or just try typing `jdb`. Both will tell you about whether jdk is present or not.

Comment: What about older version of java which does not jshell ?

Comment: @Sambit Idk, i used 9.0, just if it is somehow helpful :P